# Determining the number of decimal digits in a double - C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, double, decimal, static-cast

I am trying to get the number of digits after a decimal point in a double. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
int num_of_decimal_digits = 0;
while (someDouble - someInt != 0)
{
    someDouble = someDouble*10;
    someInt = someDouble;
    num_of_decimal_digits++;
}
```

Whenever I enter a decimal in for someDouble that is less than one, the loop gets stuck and repeats infinitely. Should I use static_cast? Any advice?

Comment: There's almost no meaningful answer to this. It's pretty much up to you to determine how many places could be significant and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Due to floating-point rounding error, multiplying by 10 is not necessarily an exact decimal shift. You can test the absolute error of the difference rather than comparing it for exact equality with `0`.

```
while (abs(someDouble - someInt) < epsilon)
```

Or you can acknowledge that a double with a 53-bit mantissa can only represent log<sub>10</sub> 2<sup>53</sup> ≈ 15.9 decimal digits, and limit the loop to 16 iterations.

```
while (someDouble - someInt != 0 && num_of_decimal_digits < 16)
```

Or both.

```
while (abs(someDouble - someInt) < epsilon && num_of_decimal_digits < 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive answer would be:

```
int num_of_decimal_digits = 0;
double absDouble = someDouble > 0 ? someDouble : someDouble * -1;
while (absDouble - someInt != 0)
{
    absDouble = absDouble*10;
    someInt = absDouble;
    num_of_decimal_digits++;
}
```

This solves your problem of negative numbers.

However, this solution is likely not going to give you the output you desire in a lot of cases because of the way that floating point numbers are represented.  For example 0.35 might really be represented as 0.3499999999998 the way floating point numbers are stored in binary.  I would suggest that you share more background information about what you are hoping to accomplish with this code (your input and your desired output).  There is likely a much better solution for what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: 0.3499999999998 is not exactly representable in IEEE 64-bit binary floating point, the commonest choice for double. The nearest representable value to 0.35 is 0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, which if anything strengthens your point.